# Check whether a character is a Vowel or Consonant

Tags: c, function, if-statement, void

I need to make Check whether a character is a Vowel or Consonant as function and it returns 1 if it's a vowel and returns 0 if it's consonant

That's what I've come up with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int vowel(char c) {
    int lowercase, uppercase;

    lowercase = (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
    uppercase = (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U');

    if (lowercase || uppercase)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    char c;

    printf("Enter an alphabet: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    vowel(c);

}
```

> Input: a
>
> Output: Process returned 0

Comment: You can't return a value in a function defined to return `void`.  The compiler must complain about your attempt to do so.  You ignore the value returned by `vowel()` — or not returned by it, depending on what you do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If i use int vowel it doesn't work anyway

Comment: In what way does it not work?  You don't pay attention to what it returns, so you've no way of telling whether it works.  You need something like `if (vowel(c)) printf("%s is a vowel\n", c); else printf("%c is not a vowel; maybe it is a consonant\n", c);`.  Strictly, you should check whether the `scanf()` call was successful too, but that's a refinement that can wait for another 10 seconds or so.

Comment: The `%s` in my previous comment should be `%c`, of course.  Apologies.  Also note that not being a vowel does not make an arbitrary character into a consonant.  It has to be a letter (`isalpha(c)`) that isn't a vowel to be a consonant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `if (vowel(c)) printf("%s is a vowel\n", c); else printf("%c is not a vowel; maybe it is a consonant\n", c);` this one works but can't get it. Like if it's 1, it's  true and if it's 0, it's false. If true - it's vowel, if false - it's consonant. Like this?

Comment: Yes.  In C, 0 is false; anything non-zero is true.  You could use `<stdbool.h>` and the `bool` type as the return type, and `true` and `false` as the return values, if you prefer.  But lots of code uses 0 for false and 1 (or other non-zero values) for true.  You'll find many comparisons written on the basis of 'zero false; non-zero true'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot, I got it. You're so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your function `int vowel(char c)` looks OK, though for readability and better compiler optimization opportunities I'd use a `switch` statement, like this:

```
int vowel(char c) {
    switch(tolower(c)){
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The second observation is that you seem to  ignore the result of the function's execution altogether. I could only assume you were supposed to do something with it, like printing out the result. Something along these lines (instead of the v̶o̶w̶e̶l̶(̶c̶)̶;̶  code):

```
printf("\nThe character '%c' is %sa vowel\n", c, vowel(c) ? "" : "not ");
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good suggestion. Though inadvertently you exemplified one of the worst features of the `printf` usage - modifying format specifiers while forgetting to adjust the argument list ;-)

Comment: That’s the advantage of comments; they’re ephemeral. That’s also the disadvantage of comments; they quickly become immutable.

Answer (score 0):

return type of vowel function is "int". But the function call is not storing the value. Change the function call as below.

```
int main() {
char c;

printf("Enter an alphabet: ");
scanf("%c", &c);
int flag = vowel(c);
printf("%d",flag);  }
```

Comment: When printing an output rather than a prompt, end the format with a newline.  It isn't absolutely necessary to save the value in a variable; you could write `printf("%d\n", vowel(c));`, but some explanation would be better.

Answer (score 0):

## Answering your questions one by one

### Firstly,

what you have is a void function called vowel that takes in a char parameter.
When you declare a type of the function, what you are basically doing is telling the system what sort of return type you are expecting from this function. Since you are declaring the function void, you are expecting no return type from it hence, it does not matter what you return there.

### Secondly,

when you declare the vowel function `int`, in your main function you have to store the value of the vowel function in a variable.

### Thirdly,

the process returned 0 that you see is mainly the execution of your program saying no errors occurred.

### What you probably are looking for is something like this I think,

```c
if (lowercase || uppercase)
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("0");
```

It's awesome to come up with own solutions,  I would also suggest following the solutions given above as they are good coding practice.

Comment: It is much better for the function to return a value than to do the printing.  It becomes generally useful if it returns an appropriate value and does no printing; it is only suited to one peculiar use if it does the printing.

Comment: The function was very quickly changed from returning `void` to returning an `int`.  Well before any answers were posted — though you might have started answering before it was changed.

Comment: Thanks , after you mention I realise that the code has been edited and you were right, I started writing the answer before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int vowel(char c) {
    int lowercase, uppercase;

    lowercase = (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
    uppercase = (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U');

    if (lowercase || uppercase)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    char c;
    printf("Enter an alphabet: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    int a=vowel(c);
    if(a==1)
        printf("vowel");
    if(a==0)
        printf("consonant");
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you're doing.  Also, note that digits are not vowels, but they are not consonants either.  Printing `consonant` is making unwarranted assumptions.  It has to be a letter that isn't a vowel to be a consonant.  It's also a good idea to make sure the output ends with a newline, and it doesn't hurt to echo the input to make validation easier (`printf("%s is a vowel\n", c)`, etc).